# Nested Logic App Asynchronous Pattern not waiting for completion

Tags: asynchronous, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to orchestrate a startup/shutdown of three VM in Azure with Logic Apps.

I've implemented the shutdown of each VM with three different Logic Apps. These Logic Apps stop some processes using an "Invoke Resource Operation" action to call some shell scripts and then deallocates the virtual machines.

And I have implemented two additional Logic Apps for orquestrate the startup and shutdown in the correct order.

But my problem is that the main Logic Apps that should orchestrate startup/shutdown are not working correctly, all child actions are executed with waiting for completion.

In the orchestration LogicApp I have enabled "Asynchronous Pattern" on the actions calling the nested Logic Apps. As an example one of the main Logic Apps:
[image]

And in the child Logic Apps, I've enabled the Asynchronous response
[image]

But my problem is that when I trigger the main Logic App all child logic Apps are called and finished without waiting for completion.I was expecting that the Asyncrhonous Pattern will poll for the execution status for completion, but for some reason it is not working.
[image]

I've noticed that in the response headers coming from the child Logic Apps executions, although the response code is 202 there is no Location header

```
{
    "statusCode": 202,
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-workflow-run-id": "08585079527234022223195797613CU48",
        "x-ms-correlation-id": "834891e6-2222-483d-b46e-d5a0fe2bd1b9",
        "x-ms-client-tracking-id": "2222079527235116808134064239CU19",
        "x-ms-trigger-history-name": "22225079527234026823195797613CU48",
        "x-ms-execution-location": "northeurope",
        "x-ms-workflow-system-id": "/locations/northeurope/scaleunits/prod-16/workflows/2222ed6cb2f143a0b895c5792f30dcf6",
        "x-ms-workflow-id": "2222d6cb2f143a0b895c5792f30dcf6",
        "x-ms-workflow-version": "22225079558278323382",
        "x-ms-workflow-name": "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX",
        "x-ms-tracking-id": "741b6bdb-2222-419b-935f-cdcc7a16bb61"
    }
}
```

Also I've noticed that when I open the Response action details of the child Logic App execution, although the response code is 202, the settings details does not reflect my original configuration.
[image]
[image]

Any idea of what problem can be?

Best regards.

Comment: If you have a response action directly after the HTTP trigger, it will return. It’s really that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my problem is that when I trigger the main Logic App all child logic Apps are called and finished without waiting for completion

Yes, that's how it works if you have a response action immediately after http request is received and I do agree with @Skin.

You need to keep response after complete actions in the child Logic apps.

[image]

Then the changed configurations you will get as response if you send something in the body about VM.

Comment: It is something strange... I updated my scenario as you said and executed it multiple times, but the result was not sucessfull. My problem was that the nested child still received additional retries after starting, and while the first one was in progress the additional ones failed with conflict.... In any case I stopped working in this topic for some days and when I started to check again it worked correctly in the first try (I did no modifications).... So my guess is that maybe it was related to some cloud replication issue.